# Is it possible to fine tune the RETURN statement to skip edges between nodes of a particular type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query of that looks something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Y {uid:42})-[r]-(b:X)-[:SUB_CLASS_OF*0..]->(:X {name:"node_of_interest"} ) 
RETURN a, r, b
```

The issue I am having is that the nodes that match `node2` tend to have LOTS of edges between them. I would like to get the links between node `a` (type Y) and node(s) that match `b` (type X), but not the edges between the different nodes that match `b`.

So to further clarify, lets say there is a single match for `a` and  `b` matches three nodes (lets call them b1, b2, b3) I would like to return a subgraph, that has the edges between (a-b1), (a-b2) and (a-b3) but **not** (b1-b2), (b1-b3) and (b2-b3).

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** added more information and tried to clarify the code as well as what is needed.

Comment: Will `RETURN DISTINCT node1, r, node2` do what you need?

Comment: @hoyski nope, unfortunately not, the edges are not duplicates. just too many irrelevant ones in the context of this query

Comment: I guess I'm not following what you're asking. From what I see in your query you're not returning the relationships between the :X labels, just the ones between the :Ys and :Xs. Can you provide a small example of the data in your graph and what you'd want the query to return for that data?

Comment: What exactly does "irrelevant" mean?

Comment: @hoyski updated the question a bit and added more details.

Comment: Are you talking about the graph viz in the browser? If yes, there is an option in Neo4j Browser to disable the automatic node connection ("Connect result nodes"), such that the relationships not returned in your statement are not displayed.

Comment: I was going to ask the same as @stellasia . That feature can be very mis-leading in the UI. I wish it were more prominent and off by default instead of on.

Comment: @stellasia that did the trick, confusing that it's a "hidden" feature that is on by default